# Get value from an html text value in php/ajax

Tags: php, mysql

I am totally stuck here and found tens of samples on posting to get and set values. What I am trying to do is -

Let a user enter a vehicles year model into a textbox in my form

I then need to get this value to a variable state

```
$vehicle_year = $_GET['vyear'];
```

First error is here... vyear is the name and id for my textbox. There is NO submission of the form etc, because I am still on the same form/page. As per my code below, I can check if a value does NOT exist... How do I get the actual entered value back?

```
$vehicle_year = isset($_POST['vehicleyear']) ? $_POST['vehicleyear'] : -1;                

            if ($vehicle_year == -1) {
            echo 'No Value Returned...';
                                //returns no value...
        } else {
                                //How to get the value and echo it out...
            echo $vehicle_year;
        }
```

With this value captured, I then search my database to return all of the manufacturers that has a year (as returned) attached to it -

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `vehicledata` WHERE `year`='$vehicle_year'";
```

Obviously it does not work because I still do not have the value as yet returned.

Comment: Does your form use `$_POST` or `$_GET` upon submission? It looks like you're mixing them up

Comment: Is your goal to use AJAX to allow the user to get a response without leaving the page? If so, can we see your AJAX code?

Comment: @relentless, I'm using POST. I do not know ajax at all. I would like to get the value using php if at all possible. Again, The form does not get posted, I need the year value ONCE a user added a value to the text box i.e. "2009". This value will enable me to retrieve data from my database...

Comment: In that case, you're only option is AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether there is any POST/GET submission data by using print_r() or var_dump() to display the contents of $_POST or $_GET, but like relentless said, it looks like you are mixing those two up.

Related:

- Don't use -1, but FALSE/NULL if you want to indicate something is not available. You can use the **identical** operator === to make sure you don't get false positives if the value you are checking for is 0.
- DON'T insert user-submitted values into your query directly. If you don't sanitize them first, your site will be vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection) attacks.

Comment: Thank you Xano, I will be sure to add the necessary security. For now I just want a kick off point to get going and make sure that I can retrieve the said data. I have in the interim changed the text input type to a select type where the user can select a year from the list. I have tried to submit the form within the onclick event (using POST), still can not retrieve the value... Any ideas maybe?